# Multiple controllers, same same controller name

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I was wondering if this is possible. Say I have a monolithic Controller, ReportController.cs.

I want to make a totally separate controller file but still keep the /Report/ in the url that we've some to know and expect.

What I tried was this in my global asax:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Testing", // Route name
    "{test}/{action}/{id}" // URL with parameters
);
```

and I added a new Controller named ReportTest.cs

the original route looks like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "LandingPage", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Every time I try to call the simple action I have in ReportTest.cs I get this error: "Value cannot be null or empty. Parameter name: controllerName"

Am I misunderstanding how this works. When you have "{controller}/.." is this not saying 'look for any controllers named  + controller and use that'. So if I go to .../Report/DoStuff it'll look for the method DoStuff on ReportController right?

So wouldn't my other route just append a search sequence? So if I put .../Report/DoStuff it'll look for the method DoStuff on ReportController and ReportTest right?

Comment: Will partial classes work?

Comment: No, partial classes help but intellisense and refactoring methods will still struggle under the weight of all that code. Leaving for a very very bad dev experience.

Comment: @CodeCaster If he uses partial controller classes, he can break up his code so that it's not all in one giant file. Does that not work?

Comment: There are a number of different potential approaches, depending on the refactoring that needs to take place here.  Partial classes are one (though "struggle under the weight of all that code" really makes me wonder what this codebase looks like...).  Perhaps attribute routing is an option?  Then the global routes and controller names become much less of an issue, you can name your controller classes whatever you like and define the routes in individual attributes.

Comment: @Josh that makes more sense. Your first comment lacks context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The routing format string:

```
{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

Means: the first part ("part" being "element after splitting on `/`") of the request URI is the controller name, the next part the action method and the last part the ID.

The placeholders `{controller}` and `{action}` are special. So your route `{test}/{action}/{id}` will not find any controller, as none is specified, and `{test}` doesn't mean anything. (Well it does, it'll get added as a route attribute named "test", and assigned a value representing that part of the request URI, so that is irrelevant for this scenario).

If you want to route an URI to a controller that is not mentioned in the URI, then you must literally specify the prefix, and the controller it should be routed to.

So your routing will look like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "SecondReportController", 
    "Report/NotOnReportController/{id}",
    new { controller = "NotAReportController" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "LandingPage", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Then you can use the following controller:

```
public class NotAReportController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult NotOnReportController(int id)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

You can of course also use attribute routing instead:

```
public class NotAReportController : Controller
{
    [Route("Report/NotOnReportController/{id}")]
    public ActionResult NotOnReportController(int id)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This works but a new route entry for every controller method doesn't seem like a very good idea :(

Comment: Multiple controllers on the same route don't seem like a good idea either. Remember that controllers only are a means of tying URIs to logic, and presenting the result of executing this logic to a view. This does not at all mean that that logic should be _in_ the controller. Perhaps you can clean up your fat controllers (which seems to be your actual problem anyway) by moving the logic into business objects.

Comment: This is true, but I was just wondering if there was greater control to how controller name parsing worked before I started gutting and moving.

Comment: The only identifier you have is `/Report/{action}`. If you have two controllers matching this route, then which one should the system instantiate to execute the `{action}`? You can of course create your own controller factory that looks up the controller implementing the `{action}` using reflection or whatever, but you really, really don't want to do that. The order is 1) Find a controller class, 2) Find the action method. MVC won't go back to step 1 if 2 was not found.

Comment: "using reflection or whatever, but you really, really don't want to do that" How come? Is reflection super inefficient?

Comment: It is, but that doesn't matter, MVC is entirely built on top of reflection. The problem is that you're going to have to reinvent the entire MVC wheel. What if both controllers implement the requested action? What if there are overloads? What if one accepts GET, and another POST? By doing this, you're digging your own grave. You're solving the wrong problem. It will be a hell to implement, a mess to maintain and in the long run you're going to regret my advice not to do it. So please, just clean up your ReportController.

Comment: Very good points. I think I'll just stick with refactoring the monolithic controller or making new distinct controllers. Thanks CodeCaste :)